# adding elements to arrayList with do while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, do-while

i can't add 2 values in this code , i tried with one variable but when i tried to fetch from user for the second time it didnt worked .so i put another one but still  i can't add value from first variable . how can i resolve this ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Suser {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c;
        String a ="";
        String b ="";
        ArrayList<String> tvList = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
        System.out.println("enter the tv show to add to the list");
        
        a = sc.nextLine();
        tvList.add(a);
        b = sc.nextLine();
        tvList.add(b);
        
        System.out.println("do you need to add more values ? if yes press Y else N ");
        
            
             c = sc.next().charAt(0);
            
        } while(c=='Y' || c=='y');
            
        System.out.println(tvList);
    }

}
```

I will give the output below

```
enter the tv show to add to the list
dark
mindhunter
do you need to add more values ? if yes press Y else N 
y
enter the tv show to add to the list
mr robot
do you need to add more values ? if yes press Y else N 
y
enter the tv show to add to the list
after life
do you need to add more values ? if yes press Y else N 
n
[dark, mindhunter, , mr robot, , after life]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the line `c=sc.next();` is executed the cursor will be at the same line so the next `a=sc.nextLine();` will parse an empty string and then move to the next line when `b=sc.nextLine();` is executed.That is why the first value is no added.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Suser {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char c;
    String a ="";
    String b ="";
    ArrayList<String> tvList = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
    System.out.println("enter the tv show to add to the list");
    
    a = sc.nextLine();
    tvList.add(a);
    b = sc.nextLine();
    tvList.add(b);
    
    System.out.println("do you need to add more values ? if yes press Y else N ");
    c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        
    } while(c=='Y' || c=='y');
        
    System.out.println(tvList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is causing `Scanner.nextLine` to be called after `Scanner.next`, causing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) issue.

Comment: how can i resolve this ? when i tried String type for the answer then it didnt loop !

Comment: Use c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0) instead of c = sc.next().charAt(0). This ensures that the newline is processed, avoiding the linked issue